# Convert to DATETIME from "Fri, 10 Jun 2016 14:30:38 -0500"

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

I am trying to pull RSS data from a page and upload it to my database.

example:

```
<dc:date>Fri, 10 Jun 2016 14:30:38 -0500</dc:date>
```

the -0500 is the trouble.

what I usually do:

```
    $dc1 = $xml->channel->item[$i]->children($namespaces["dc"]);
    $pubDate1 = $dc1->date;
    $pubDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $pubDate1)));
```

Should I be defining $pubDate differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of replacing '-' with '/'. You can directly pass the $pubDate1

```
$dc1 = $xml->channel->item[$i]->children($namespaces["dc"]);
$pubDate1 = $dc1->date; // 'Fri, 10 Jun 2016 14:30:38 -0500'
$pubDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($pubDate1));
```

OutPut :

2016-06-11 12:30:38

Answer (score 0):

If all of your date have the last part, maybe this code works. but if the last part(-0500) appears in some of them it wont work:

```
$dc1 = $xml->channel->item[$i]->children($namespaces["dc"]);
$pubDate1 = explode(' ',$dc1->date);
// remove -0500 
array_pop($pubDate1);
$pubDate1 = implode(' ',$pubDate1);
$pubDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($pubDate1));
```

Comment: thank you! Will check this as the answer when i can.